# Async WMI query for Win32_LocalTime does not fire events

Tags: asynchronous, singleton, wmi

I am usually do most of my wmi queries asnyc and normally, I have no
problem with them. I setup a ManangementScope with all privileges and
the necessary dcom security [for remote queries]. A little shorted snippet of the whole code is like this:

```
ManagementPath mp = new ManagementPath();
mp.NamespacePath = @"\root\cimv2";
mp.Server = computerName;

this.ms = new ManagementScope(mp, co);  //privs + dcom [outside]
this.ms.Connect();

EventQuery eq = new EventQuery(query);
ManagementEventWatcher mew = new ManagementEventWatcher(this.ms, eq);

mew.EventArrived += new  EventArrivedEventHandler(this.OnEventArrived);
mew.Stopped += new StoppedEventHandler(this.OnStopped);

mew.Start();
```

As mentioned, rarely have a problem with this, but now :-(
The class queryed is 'Win32_LocalTime' and the query starts, but
do not give any events. In WBemTest, this works !

This is the query:

```
select * from __InstanceModificationEvent where targetinstance isa 'Win32_LocalTime'
```

One thing, I see is, that the class is a singleton and I would probably
have to use a special syntax to specify the singleton class in the query, but I cannot figure it out.

Additionally, I tried one async query with powershell and it worked. Then, I used PS to query 'Win32_LocalTime' and is does NOT work !!

A tip, hint or pointer to further information would
be really great!

Thanks so far and
best regards

++mabra

Comment: Try specifying the polling interval like so `Select * From __InstanceModificationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LocalTime'`

Comment: Thanks, your are right, it is not an eventclass. It was - at one point - just another try. After the main problem [see my own answer] was solved, I got the error message, saying exactly this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved , "accidentally" .... ;-)

The problem is in my eventhandler. In that, I am accessing the
NewEvent.SystemProperties["Server"] which is null and the
thread dies without notice.

Astounding, how many situation I am seeing, where threads die without
notice [I had the same thing with the System.Timers.Timer and after a debate, MS said, they will not change this behavior :-( ].

Until I used the show query, it was meant as a little "event diagnoser",
I have never seen SystemProperties.Server beeing empty :-(

I'll change some code now.

Anyway, best regards !

++mabra